# Finding the rate of change in volume using chain rule and partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I have a question for homework I am suffering with, the question is:

A steel bar with square cross sections $5 \operatorname{cm}$ by $5 \operatorname{cm}$ and length $4 \operatorname{m} $ is being heated. For each dimension, the bar expands $13\cdot10^{-6} \operatorname{m} $ for each $1\operatorname{C°} $ rise in temperature. The answer will be in the format of $\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} = \underline{ } \cdot 10^{-6} \operatorname {m^3/C°}$. A hint given reads: Let the square cross section have side length $x(T)$ and the bar have length $L(T)$ at temperature $T$ degrees Celsius. Letting $V$ be the volume of the bar, the chain rule gives $\frac{\partial V} {\partial T} =\frac{\partial V} {\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial T} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial L}\frac{\partial L}{\partial T}$

I didn't really know where to start so I found the base volume $(5\cdot5\cdot400) = 10000$, and the updated volume after a change of $1$ degree $(5\cdot (13\cdot 10^{-6} )\cdots) = 10000.39001$, and subtracted the second from the first, and got $0.39$ but that seems too big given the answer format given.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For what it's worth, I (also) am unsure of the right answer, so I deleted an answer that I originally posted.  Upon reflection, it seems that, in apparent conflict with the posted formula, you are supposed to examine the change in each of the $3$ dimensions $(0.05), (0.05),$ and $(4)$ separately.  This seems to lead to the computation of $$\left[ ~ 1.3 \times 10^{-6}\right] \times \left\{ ~\left[2 \times (0.05) \times 4 \right] + \left[(0.05)^2\right] ~\right\}.$$  Unfortunately, my knowledge in this area is so weak that I am **just guessing**.

Comment: @user2661923  That is a good approximation.

Answer (score 1):

> I didn't really know where to start

You were told where to start in the first paragraph.

Just apply the Chain Rule to the formula for the volume of a square-based rectangular prism.

To shorten typing, let $c=13\cdot 10^{-6}~\textrm m~{^\circ \mathrm C}^{-1}$

$\begin{align}x(T) &= (0.05+c~T)~\text{m}
\\[2ex]\ell(T)&=(4+c~T)~\text{m}\\[2ex]V(T) &= x^2(T)~\ell(T)\\&=(0.05+cT)^2~(4+cT)~\text{m}^3
\\[2ex]\left.\dfrac{\mathrm d V}{\mathrm d T}\right\rvert_{T=1} &= \end{align}$